# Why are we not getting the most stable product in Aldol condensation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

The picture above is from my class notes. I am familiar with the mechanism of both acid and base catalysed Aldol condensation. I also understand the reason why KCP was told as the major product in base catalysed Aldol condensation. But we know that Aldol condensation is reversible throughout so shouldn't TCP product be major all the time?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation. Are both steps reversible (addition AND dehydration)? The other observation is that in 'real' synthesis one usually tends to look for conditions that favour the desired product, rather than allowing equilibration and conversion of the products to undesired side products. Think of Michael additions: those are indeed reversible _on paper_. But then no Michael addition product should exist or be stable. I am trying to make you reflect on the fact that the reaction conditions are very important.

Comment: Yes your last line is important. What I have understood is that dehydration would become reversible if enough temperature is provided. So, you can keep the temperature a bit low and get the desired result. Am I correct?

Comment: Not sure about this specific case, but there is a general principle: 'kinetic' products tend to be favoured by low temperatures, and 'thermodynamic' products tend to be favoured by higher temperatures. E.g. in reactions involving organometallic species, low temperatures and the use of a strong base may favour the abstraction of the kinetically preferred proton, whereas higher temperatures and a weaker base may lead to the formation of a mixture, with a prevalence of the most stable anion.
But for your case I think it's more important to check if some reactions are reversible at all.